# Illustrator: Select next object above and below in isolation mode

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

In Illustrator, it's [not currently possible](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html#select_the_next_object_in_the_stacking_order) to use <kbd>Select</kbd> > <kbd>Next Object Above / Below</kbd> when working in isolation mode, e.g. artwork inside a clipping mask.

I can still open the layers palette and see the stacking order in the isolation mode, and select artwork there that is otherwise tricky to select. This is a bit cumbersome though.

**Does anyone have a quick way to select the next object above / below while in isolation mode?**

I have made a [feature request](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1896028) for this functionality.

Comment: Layers Panel doesn't work?

Comment: I am using CC 2015 and am able to click the small disclosure triangles in the layers panel, whilst in isolation mode, to see layered objects inside a clipping mask.

Comment: @Scott I may have misread your comment - did you mean to suggest using the layers panel? If so, yes I can, but it's rather cumbersome workaround when there are lots of objects that can be hard to identify.

Comment: Josh, the currently selected object is highlighted in the layers panel. The next object above/below is right there above/below the highlight.  I do realize for large groups, you may need to scroll the Layers panel, but I believe that's the best you'll get.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The highlight helps. Looks like there is nothing easier (or accessible via keyboard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best you can do is to utilize the **Layers Panel**.

The currently selected object will be highlighted by a small color box to the right of the object name in the Layers Panel. The next object above/below will be above/below that highlight.

[image]

Just click the circle on the right of the object above/below to select it.

Not an ideal solution, I realize. And for large isolations it may require scrolling the Layers Panel, which again, I realize isn't ideal. But as far as I'm aware, this is about the best you'll get until Adobe allows the selection menu items to work in Isolation Mode. Unfortunately, those are the only keyboard navigation commands for the Layer Panel in Illustrator I'm aware of.